# Async Test in Jasmine 2.6

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, bdd, jasmine2.0

The syntax for async tests has changed since 2.x and the [documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/2.6/introduction) is not clear.

Can someone clarify how I execute some code, block for 3 seconds, and then run a test condition using the new syntax?

```
it('should update the table when new data is provided', function() {
  var newData = ",0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23\nX-Y,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1";

  fixture.datum(csv).call(fp);

  expect(fp.dataset()).toEqual(csv);

  fp.dataset(newData);

  expect(fp.dataset()).toEqual(newData);

  //block for 3 seconds
  expect(fixture.selectAll(".row").nodes().length).toBe(3);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*done* needs to be passed as a parameter to a spec, and *done()* needs to be called as the last statement in the *setTimeout()* block.

If the async spec exceeds 5sec in total, it will fail, see jasmine docs excerpt for more info:

> By default jasmine will wait for 5 seconds for an asynchronous spec to finish before causing a timeout failure. If the timeout expires before done is called, the current spec will be marked as failed and suite execution will continue as if done was called.
>
> If specific specs should fail faster or need more time this can be adjusted >by passing a timeout value to it, etc.

```
it('should update the table when new data is provided', function(done) {
  var newData = ",0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23\nX-Y,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1";

  fixture.datum(csv).call(fp);

  expect(fp.dataset()).toEqual(csv);

  fp.dataset(newData);

  expect(fp.dataset()).toEqual(newData);

  //block for 3 seconds, then execute expect
  setTimeout(function() {
      expect(fixture.selectAll(".row").nodes().length).toBe(3);
      done(); //dont forget!!
  }, 3000);

});
```